# Locking on a collection, then creating a new instance of the collection. Dangerous?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, collections, locking

I'm currently working on a multi-threaded interface for a few hardware devices, and I was storing my polling packet in a List collection. Since this interface needs to be very thread safe, I've taken to locking the collection every time I want to make changes to it. I've found through running diagnostics that creating a new instance of the collection is much faster than clearing it and then adding a new range of values for the poll. I was wanting to know if doing this though would cause issues with the locking, as I have limited experience with multi-threading applications and even less experience locking on a collection rather than a SyncRoot object.

Here's an example snippet for comparison:

```
lock (Poll)
{
    Poll = new List<byte>(new byte[] { START, 0x00, STATUS_REQUEST, 0x00, 0x00});
}
```

Versus....

```
lock (Poll)
{
    Poll.Clear();
    Poll.AddRange(new byte[] { START, ZERO, STATUS_REQUEST, ZERO, ZERO });
}
```

Edit: Wanted to note that the Poll object is not publicly exposed. That's a no-no.

Comment: Your first code snippet locks on and object referred to by `Poll` then replaces the reference with a completely new instance. Now a second thread can enter the lock, because when they lock on `Poll`, they'll be locking on a different object. Although all the work in the lock would be complete, the risk comes when you decide to put something else in the same locked section. Subtle bug ahoy.

Comment: Your first example the lock is not necessary, assignments to `class` objects  is atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've likely already read that you should not be locking on any public properties/`this` skipping that part of the problem.

`lock(Poll) { Poll = new ... }` is just wrong - don't even try; `lock (Poll) { Poll.Clear();...{` is against "don't lock on public objects" guidance, but at least will achieve desired effect.

`lock` statement uses current value of variable as gate, if value changes later it may not properly block another thread from re-entering the same piece of code under `lock`.

`lock(Poll) { Poll = new ... }` will lock on `Poll` object and whoever have the same object cached locally can continue locking and being prevented from re-entering this code. Code that just `lock(Poll) {...}` will unlikely be able to get the same value of `Poll` variable when it is being assigned and probably enter the same block of code.

Correct code:

```
object lockPoll = new object(); // stays the same over `Poll` property lifetime
...

lock(lockPoll)
{
   // code that accesses or changes Poll 
   // both Poll = new ... or Poll.Clear() are fine
}
```

Comment: The Poll object isn't exposed, the interface methods simply make a change to the collection (changing a few bytes), and then uses an Eventwaithandle to block until a specific response is received from the device or there's a timeout. 

Thank you though. Answer accepted.